# Show that R is a skew field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity such that the only left ideals of $R$ are $\{0\}$ and $R$. Show that $R$ is a skew field.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: If $x\neq0$ what can you say about the left ideal it generates?

Comment: The definition of skew field might be a good start.  Do you know that?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I know that in skew field every non-zero elements is a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\neq 0$ .

Consider $Ra$ .(Show that it is a left ideal of $R$).

$a=1.a\in Ra\implies Ra\neq \{0\}$.

Conclusion $Ra=R\implies \exists b\in R$ such that $ba=1$.

To conclude the proof show that $ab=ba=1$(How?)

> Also similarly $Rb=R\implies cb=1 $ for some $c\in R$.Now $a=1.a=(cb).a=c.(ba)=c.1=c$

Comment: how you have concluded Ra=R

Comment: thanks. it is correct. i know that in skew field every non-zero elements is a unit. have you used this definition to prove skew field? How ba=1 imply ab=1

Comment: @user1942348 Yes, that's what he has done. He's proven that any non-zero element generates a left ideal with $1$ in it, and therefore must have an inverse.

Comment: Bcs $Ra$ is a left ideal and only left ideals are $R$ and $\{0\}$

Comment: @user1942348;see my edits by hovering you mouse over shaded part